# Errno 13 Permission denied error trying to read pcap file

Tags: python, bash, permissions, scapy

When I use [scapy's](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) `Scapy.rdpcap` function to read a pcap file for analysis, it raises a `Permission denied` error.
The line of code is：

```py
pcap=rdpcap('../Data/network_sim.pcap')
```

Error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '../Data/network_sim.pcap'
```

I don't understand why I'm receiving this error.

Comment: You need to show what `rdpcap` is doing with the string it reads. My guess it that it interprets the string as filename and tries to open it. I would therefore (for debugging) check that the file can be opened, by opening it with `open(....)`. If this does **not** result in an error message, I would have a look inside the code for `rdpcap` to see what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not have the permissions to read the `'../Data/network_sim.pcap'` file, add the read permissions to the file  :

```bash
chmod +r ../Data/network_sim.pcap
```

read more about [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)